# Base16 colors break under tmux ssh

Tags: ssh, zsh, tmux

I'm using the same dot files for all my machines.

On my local machine everything works just fine in tmux, when sshing over to 
one of my machines the colors breaks. Colors also work sshing in general outside of tmux.

General settings can be seen in the image

[image: see image]

Comment: What is tmux the version you are using on remote machine?

Comment: I'm not using a tmux session on the remote machine. I filed a bug report on base16 shell. Since I'm not running a tmux session remotely the $TMUX env is not set. That is what breaks the RGBs in each base16 script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is not tmux session running on the remote host (tmux running locally with ssh happening in one of the panes), there is no `$TMUX` environment variable set.

Base16 script expects there to be such a flag for RGBs to be properly set

```
     if [ -n "$TMUX" ]; then
      # Tell tmux to pass the escape sequences through
      # (Source: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.terminal-emulators.tmux.user/1324)
      put_template() { printf '\033Ptmux;\033\033]4;%d;rgb:%s\033\033\\\033\\' $@; }
      put_template_var() { printf '\033Ptmux;\033\033]%d;rgb:%s\033\033\\\033\\' $@; }
      put_template_custom() { printf '\033Ptmux;\033\033]%s%s\033\033\\\033\\' $@; }
     elif [ "${TERM%%[-.]*}" = "screen" ]; then
    ...
```

Workaround is currently to fix the if statement in each script.